# how to know know when the user changes zoom level on the map view in ArcGIS iOS SDK

Tags: ios, zooming, arcgis

I want to know when the user changes zoom level on the mapview, because i want to control somethings. For example i won't show some map layers when the zoom level less 5.

I want method like Android API's 'setOnZoomListener(OnZoomListener)'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observer for when the maps extent changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mapExtentChanged:) name:AGSMapViewDidEndZoomingNotification object:nil];
```

Then in your method you can check your maps scale:

```
- (void)mapExtentChanged: (NSNotification*) notification {
    // Check if your map scale is equal to zoom level 5
    // Do something... 
}
```